# Save Best time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can you save your highscore in unity? I am working on a game which has a timer, my plan is to save the best time you got.

Here is the code for the timer:

[image: Timer]

I have tried to save the best time but it doesn't work without a button.

Here is the code for the Highscore saver:

[image: Highscoresaver]

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: And well you only store and load `Score` .. you also want to store and load the time so implement a method for getting it from the `Timer` class ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you store/load the `Score` field you also want to have one for the time like

```
public float BestTime;
```

and then get the time from your `Timer` class e.g. like

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    .....


    public float GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return Time.time - startTime;
    }
}
```

And then within your `HighScore` (or if you like directly in the `Timer` depending on your needs and preferences) do

```
[SerializeField] private Timer timer;

private void Start()
{
    ...
    BestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(nameof(BestTime));
}

private void Update ()
{
    ...

    var currentTime = timer.GetCurrentTime();

    if(currentTime > BestTime)
    {
        // Make sure to also update the local field
        BestTime = currentTime;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(nameof(BestTime), currentTime);
    }
}
```

You should btw also do

```
if(Score > highscore)
{
    highscore = Score;
    ...
}
```

---

Also have in mind that in certain intervals you might want to call [`PlayerPrefs.Save`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html).

And instead of updating the next and highscore in `Update` so **every frame** you should rather move at least the part for the `Score` into the `AddScore` and `Start` methods so it is only updated **once** when necessary.